# executing script on remote host by ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I wrote a script test.sh (its function is the same as "hostname" command) as below,

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "`uname -a | awk '{print $2;}'` "
```

I can get my hostname with

```
source /home/arton/test.sh
```

or

```
/home/arton/test.sh
```

Then, I issued the command

```
ssh myhost "source /home/arton/test.sh"
```

and expected getting "myhost", but I got total output of uname -a

```
Linux myhost 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 ...
```

After try and error, the commands below can output "myhost"

```
ssh myhost "/home/arton/test.sh"
ssh myhost "bash -s" < /home/arton/test.sh
```

But I still have no idea why this happens.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, it works fine on my system.

Comment: I always get the output of "uname -a" when I issue the command: ssh myhost "source /home/arton/test.sh". Don't know if the env will affect the behavior or not.

Comment: Are you aware you sometimes refer to the local file `/home/arton/test.sh`, but sometimes to the same path on the *remote* machine? What is the remote user's shell? Is it `csh` maybe?

Comment: Yeah, I am aware I refer to the same path on the different host, but all the hosts in our local network mount the same file system. You are right! The logging shell is csh, and it is the problem. I tested the script with bash when I posted the question. I should have used ssh myhost "/home/arton/test.sh" instead of ssh myhost "source /home/arton/test.sh".